# Embedded Firmware Architecture

Tags: c, firmware

I’ve been writing increasingly complex firmware and am starting to notice that my knowledge of design patterns and architecture is a bit lacking. I’m trying to work on developing these skills and am hoping for some input. Note: this is for embedded c for microcontrollers.

I’m working with a concept for a new project as an exercise right now that goes something like this:

1. We have a battery management module with user I/O
2. The main controller is responsible for I/O (button, LCD, UART debug), detecting things like the charger being plugged in/unplugged, and managing high level operations.
3. The sub controller is a battery management controller (pretty much a custom PMIC) capable of monitoring battery levels, running charging/discharging firmware etc.
4. The PMIC interfaces with a fuel gauge IC that it uses to read battery information from
5. The interface between the two controllers, fuel gauge and the LCD are all I2C

Here is a rough system diagram:

[image]

Now what I’m trying to do is to come up with a good firmware architecture that will allow for expandability (adding multiple batteries, adding more sensors, changing the LCD (or other) interface from I2C to SPI, etc), and for testing (simulate button presses via UART, replace battery readings with simulated values to test PMIC charge firmware, etc).

What I would normally do is write a custom driver for each peripheral, and a firmware module for each block. I would implement a flagging module as well with a globally available get/set that would be used throughout the system. For example my timers would set 100Hz, 5Hz, 1Hz, flags, which the main loop would handle and call the individual modules at their desired rate. Then the modules themselves could set flags for the main loop to handle for events like I2C transaction complete, transaction timed out, temperature exceeded, etc.

What I am hoping to get from this is a few suggestions on a better way to architect the system to achieve my goals of scalability, encapsulation and abstraction. It seems like what I’m doing is sort of a pseudo event-driven system but one that’s been hacked together.
In any case here’s my attempt at an architecture diagram:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What processor are you using? There are free preemptive operating systems for the common embedded processors like ARM, Micro Blaze, ... .

Comment: There is no specific processor. Just a conceptual design at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of an "event bus" is over-complicated.  In many cases, the simplest approach is to minimize the number of things that need to happen asynchronously, but instead have a "main poll" routine which runs on an "as often as convenient" basis and calls polling routines for each subsystem.  It may be helpful to have such routine in a compilation by itself, so that the essence of that file would simply be a list of all polling functions used by other subsystems, rather than anything with semantics of its own.  If one has a "get button push" routine, one can have a loop within that routine which calls the main poll routine until a button is pushed, there's a keyboard timeout, or something else happens that the caller needs to deal with.  That would then allow the main UI to be implemented using code like:

```
void maybe_do_something_fun(void)
{
  while(1)
  {
    show_message("Do something fun?");
    wait_for_button();
    if (button_hit(YES_BUTTON))
    {
      ... do something fun
      return;
    }
    else if (button_hit(NO_BUTTON))
    {
      ... do something boring
      return;
    }
  } while(1);
}
```

This is often much more convenient than trying to have a giant state machine and say that if the code is the `STATE_MAYBE_DO_SOMETHING_FUN` state and the `yes` or `no` button is pushed, it will need to advance to the `STATE_START_DOING_SOMETHING_FUN` or `STATE_START_DOING_SOMETHING_BORING` state.

Note that if one uses this approach, one will need to ensure that the worst-case time between calls to main_poll will always satisfy the timeliness requirements of the polling operations handled through `main_poll`, but in cases where that requirement can be met, this approach can be far more convenient and efficient than doing everything necessary to preemptively-scheduled multi-threaded code along with the locks and other guards needed to make it work reliably.

Comment: I would add that, instead of a big if/elseif block, one could register command/callback pairs to a table that will be looked up at each cycle refresh, to improve modularity and extendibility

However, if you add a queue of these commands that is dequeued at each polling iteration, and if you add a global 'enqueue' function, you will just achieve e message bus architecture

Comment: @sscnapoli1926: In many cases (especially on devices with small screens, but also sometimes with wizard-based UIs), the most natural way of describing a UI is with a flowchart which has many different boxes that read a character.  One could use an event registration system, but registering handlers for "yes" and "no" buttons, showing a prompt, and then having the handler for either button perform the appropriate action, unregister than handlers, and then showing the next prompt and registering handlers for it, etc. is apt to be far messier than simply using if/else logic.

Comment: As demonstrated by the failure of the ancient Apple /// in 1984 which tried to implement an event driven system on the humble 6502 processor. That processor had been used to good effect with Apple ][ but overstretched the ability of the hardware and software designs.

Comment: @supercat totally agree....but if the requirement is to add abstraction, scalability and encapulation (that maybe together form the concept of 'extendibility') i would also think about a dynamic mechanism to dispatch command

Comment: @sscnapoli1926: If a user will need to be able to interact with several aspects of the interface in arbitrary order, it will be necessary to use either state-machine or event-driven logic for all but one of them.  For the scenario where the number of independent aspects is one, however, the state or event logic wouldn't need to handle any aspects of state and may as well not exist unless or until it becomes necessary, whereupon it could be added to the "main poll" routine.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your meaning. It looks like "wait_for_button();" would block in the above example. How are you able to poll the other subsystem polling routines?

Comment: @Otus: The `wait_for_button()` routine *itself* would call all the other polling routines while it's waiting for the button.

Comment: @supercat How do you handle when there are multiple sources to monitor. Maybe we're waiting on a button push, or a watchdog timeout, or an over temperature condition that needs to be monitored via an I2C interface, etc?

Comment: @Otus: The `wait_for_button()` function may exit early for certain things that aren't actual button pushes, but need to trigger some UI interaction.  One of my programs using this approach has two such kinds of "dummy" button pushes--one for things that should spin around the immediate surrounding loop [which, among other things, redraws the prompt] and one of which requests that the UI exit the current context [used for things like keyboard timeouts].  Many other events are handled by state machines which are handled within the poll() functions called by `wait_for_button()`.

Comment: @Otus: Incidentally, most of the timers used by my program are passively polled, but if none of the polling tasks indicate that they want the CPU to stay awake, and no button is pushed, `wait_for_button()` can determine which timer is set to expire first, and then put the CPU to sleep until either an external event occurs or enough time elapses for a timer to expire.  Handling that within `wait_for_button()` is easier than having to intermingle sleep logic within the UI code.